# Number of calls of recursive function with python decorators

Tags: python-3.x, python-decorators

I have the following code chunk about **functional decorators** where I wanted to initialize the variable `wrapper.calls` to be 0 from the second time I call `fib()` knowing that at the first run it gives the correct answer and after, it behaves as summing previous outputs. My question is how to fix this with changing only decorator profiler, please?

**Here is my code:**

```
from functools import wraps
import time


def profiler(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        wrapper.calls += 1
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    wrapper.calls = 0
    return wrapper

@profiler
def fib(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)


fib(1)
print(fib.calls)
fib(2)
print(fib.calls)
```

**Output of this program after execution:**

```
1
4
```

**Expected output**

```
1 
3
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
def profiler(func):

    calls = 0

    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs): 
        nonlocal calls
        if not calls:
            wrapper.calls = 0

        calls += 1
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        calls -= 1
        wrapper.calls += 1

        return result
    return wrapper
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `calls = 0` are only initialized at the `fib = profiler(fib)`.

If you only execute

```
fib(2)
print(fib.calls)
```

it will be **3**

or

```
for input_n in (1, 2):
    fib = profiler(fib)
    fib(input_n)
    print(fib.calls)
```

Will be what you expect

```
1
3
```

Comment: I want to change decorator profiler to avoid this situation (**output of this program after execution**) but not the code of callings the function `fib()`.